is there any possible simplification of the SQL PIVOT operator?
Assume I have a table with just 3 columns: state, date, amount
representing many individual amounts per day being recorded.
I want to write a query like this:
select date, sum(amount) pivot by state;

to produce output that has one row per date, and a column for every state with the sum of all the revenue_amounts for that day.
Instead, I have to create a subquery, figure out what all possible values of state are and code those in or use dynamic SQL. Yes, I can ask chatgpt. But I am curious, for this common, trivial query, (using Microsoft Transact-SQL) is there some way to write it close to the simple line I wrote above?
I can achieve the desired outcome with something like this code, but am too lazy to type this much and troubleshoot it when I want something I can type and get results in 5 seconds:
-- Declare variables for dynamic SQL
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Get the distinct state names and format them for the PIVOT clause
SET @columns = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(state)
    FROM Sales
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '', '');

-- Build the dynamic SQL query
SET @sql = '
SELECT [date], ' + @columns + '
FROM (
    SELECT [date], [state], [amount]
    FROM Sales
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(amount)
    FOR state IN (' + @columns + ')
) AS PivotTable;';

-- Execute the dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


Why use the "old" FOR XML PATH method for string aggregation as well? Why not use STRING_AGG?

TSQL (or SQL Server) has this annoying attribute that every query that generates data needs to have number of columns it generates ahead of time. For this reason, the above syntax won't be possible, since it would implicate a dynamic column list, which just isn't done. Although i suspect it might cheat when it comes to OPENQUERY but it doesn't seem to want to do it in general code, probably because it becomes slow. In another life, i wrote a procedure that accepts a source table, pivot column, pivot function etc and generated the above for me, it saved a lot of time

If you are asking "is there a trivial way to do a dynamic pivot" then the answer is "don't do it in T-SQL". Whenever I see these type of requirements they are almost always for reports, which have built-in tools to achieve these types of results. For example, SSRS has Matrixes.

If the question is just "are there alternatives to PIVOT, then conditional aggregation is what you want; it's far less restrictive (try doing a COUNT and SUM in the same PIVOT, emulating GROUPING_SETS, or adding/removing additional columns to the pivoted value(s)) and (I think) much more easy to understand.

You're jumping through hoops to make a "dynamic" pivot. Those hoops exist because SQL is explicitly designed to not have dynamic result-set shapes/signatures (the number of columns, their names, their data types is fixed). This is because the SQL language works best on normalised data structures. In short, you're fighting against the intention and design of the language. In the vast majority of cases this is advised against and is considered a code smell. Reformat the data outside of your database (in the application or reporting layer) and keep a normalised structure inside the database

Thanks; I believe the answer to my question is "use Excel or some other BI tool" because there is no trivial way to do a dynamic pivot directly in T-SQL. My use case is "interactive" and "managerial," e.g. I am exploring the data, validating the data, etc. So right-click, copy with headers, paste to excel, insert pivot table...

This looks like a comment rather than an answer. Please use comments for that

I tried to close the loop and not leave it out there so that someone would read it and waste time composing another answer.

The query won't write for you, nor does it know what is in your data. The closest thing would be to create a SQL script or SP that dynamically generates the query as output and just always use that.
A more simplistic approach from a syntax standpoint that I often see people take is to SUM CASE expressions instead of using PIVOT. This yields the same outcome; however you need to know what you are interested in aggregating or else use something to automate the unknown, mentioned above.
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'TX' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS TX,
   SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'NY' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS NY,
   SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'FL' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS FL
FROM
   Table


The Aggregate + CASE syntax is known as "conditional aggregation".

@Thom A - Thanks for the info. I did not know that.

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions; couple notes:

STRING_AGG not supported yet in my version of MSSQL
conditional aggregation is useful for many things, but still a lot of typing for my need
Excel is my answer.

